# How to hide form-group input box with label in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, symfony

How to hide form-group input box with label in `jquery`?

- formcode.twig file html code:

```html
<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="4c609cf1bbb6c5080865df9cfc1fb649_code_details_ctk_code" class="col-sm-4 control-label">
    Code</label>

  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <div class="input-group col-lg-7 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <input type="text" class="form-control  pull-left" id="4c609cf1bbb6c5080865df9cfc1fb649_code_details_ctk_code" value=""><span class="input-group-addon dt_col_show_hide_trigger">
             <div class="bootstrap-switch bootstrap-switch-wrapper bootstrap- switch-on bootstrap-switch-id-show_hide_4c609cf1bbb6c5080865df9cfc1fb649_code_details_ctk_code_trigger bootstrap-switch-animate" style="width: 109.5px;"><div class="bootstrap-switch-container" style="width: 160px; margin-left: 0px;"><span class="bootstrap-switch-handle-on bootstrap-switch-primary" style="width: 53px;">Hide</span>
      <span
      class="bootstrap-switch-label" style="width: 53px;">&nbsp;</span><span class="bootstrap-switch-handle-off bootstrap-switch-default" style="width: 53px;">Show</span>
        <input id="show_hide_4c609cf1bbb6c5080865df9cfc1fb649_code_details_ctk_code_trigger" type="checkbox" value="Y" checked="checked">
    </div>
  </div>
  </span>
</div><span class="help-block">
    </span>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: Add more details Please

Answer (score 0):

This is using for hide.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#4c609cf1bbb6c5080865df9cfc1fb649_code_details_ctk_code').parents('.form-group').hide();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In CSS:

```
.form-control{
    display:none; }
```

In javascript:

```
 $('.form-control').hide();
```